# Intent: cannot proceed to next activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

The intent keeps showing the same activity and does not proceed to the next activity according to the counter that is stored in a firebase real-time database. The reason why there is a counter is that I want to reuse the EditPetDetail activity.

I have tried a couple of `setFlags`, `removeExtra` in the `EditPetDetail` activity, `finish()`, looking at the android manifest file and it still shows the same activity layout after proceeding into the appropriate function.

As for the `removeExtra`, I wrote the code after transferring the data of the extras into the variables.

This is the function inside the Device Activity.

```java
    public void EditPet(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditPetDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("dbDevice", deviceno);
        intent.putExtra("dbName", nameID);
        intent.putExtra("dbAge", ageID);
        intent.putExtra("dbWeight", weightID);
        intent.putExtra("dbType", typeID);
        intent.putExtra("dbCounter", counter);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

This is the function inside the `EditPetDetail` Activity.

```java
    public void MainPage(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "123", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void PetDetail(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nononope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, pet_detail.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is the android manifest activity names.

```
 <activity android:name=".EditPetDetail"></activity>
 <activity android:name=".Device">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
 <activity android:name=".pet_detail" />
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

I expected the activity to proceed to the different functions based on whether the counter is 0 or 1, but it didn't work. I also used a toast to make sure that it is going to the right function, but in the end after the animation, it just showed me the same activity without any fields in the `EditText`.

Comment: Is there any exception in logcat?

Comment: There is this:
"E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory"

          And lots of these:
"Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:484157558 intent:Intent { cmp=com.example.fyp/.EditPetDetail (has extras) }"